Are two smooth structures yielding nested sets of smooth real-valued functions equivalent?
Let $ M $ be a smooth manifold that is second countable and $ C^{\infty} $. Suppose $ \mathcal{A} $ and $ \mathcal{B} $ are two smooth structures on $ M $, and denote the set of smooth real-valued functions on $ M $ with respect to these structures by $ C^{\infty}_{\mathcal{A}}(M) $ and $ C^{\infty}_{\mathcal{B}}(M) $, respectively.
I want to know if the following implications hold:
$$
C^{\infty}_{\mathcal{A}}(M) \subseteq C^{\infty}_{\mathcal{B}}(M) \Longrightarrow C^{\infty}_{\mathcal{A}}(M) = C^{\infty}_{\mathcal{B}}(M) \Longrightarrow \mathcal{A} = \mathcal{B} \Longrightarrow C^{\infty}_{\mathcal{A}}(M)=C^{\infty}_{\mathcal{B}}(M)
$$
The third implication is trivial. The second implication seems straightforward to verify: by taking subcovers of $ \mathcal{A} $ and $ \mathcal{B} $, we can ensure that for each chart $ (U, \varphi) $ in the subcover of $ \mathcal{A} $(the subcover of $ \mathcal{B} $), there exists $ \tilde{\varphi}\in C^{\infty}_{\mathcal A}=C^{\infty}_{\mathcal B} $ such that $ \varphi = \tilde{\varphi}|_U $ . From this, we can show that the union of the two set of coordinate charts is compatible, which leads to $ \mathcal{A} = \mathcal{B} $.
However, I am uncertain whether the first implication holds. Is it true that if $ C^{\infty}_{\mathcal{A}}(M) \subseteq C^{\infty}_{\mathcal{B}}(M) $, then $ \mathcal{A}=\mathcal{B} $?
Any insights or counterexamples would be appreciated!

Your argument does not quite work. Indeed, if you take $M=\mathbb{R}$ with the standard smooth structure and the chart $\varphi\colon U=\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}\rightarrow\mathbb{R},\,x\mapsto\frac{1}{x}$, then there is no smooth (or even continuous) $\overline{\varphi}\colon\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ s.t. $\overline{\varphi}\vert_U=\varphi$.
Furthermore, the first implication is not true. Indeed, if you let $\mathcal{A}$ be the smooth structure on $M=\mathbb{R}$ generated by the chart $M\rightarrow\mathbb{R},\,x\mapsto\sqrt[3]{x}$, then $C^{\infty}_{\mathcal{A}}(M)$ is the set of those functions $f\colon\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ s.t. $f\circ(-)^3$ is a smooth function. The cube function is smooth, so $C^{\infty}(M)\subseteq C^{\infty}_{\mathcal{A}}(M)$, but the cube root function is not smooth, so $\mathcal{A}$ does not agree with the standard atlas.
However, here is a variation of your argument that does demonstrate the second implication. Suppose $C^{\infty}_{\mathcal{A}}(M)=C^{\infty}_{\mathcal{B}}(M)$ for two smooth structures $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}$ on the smoothable manifold $M$. Now, let $(U,\varphi)$ be any chart for the smooth structure $\mathcal{A}$. For any point $p\in U$, we can use a bump function to find an open neighborhood $p\in V\subseteq U$ and a $\psi\in C^{\infty}_{\mathcal{A}}(M)$ s.t. $\psi\vert_V=\varphi\vert_V$. The assumption implies that $\psi$ is also smooth w.r.t. $\mathcal{B}$, hence $\varphi$ is smooth w.r.t. $\mathcal{B}$ at $p$. The point $p\in U$ was arbitrary, hence $\varphi$ is smooth w.r.t. $\mathcal{B}$. The roles of $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ may be reversed to see that likewise any chart of $\mathcal{B}$ is smooth w.r.t. $\mathcal{A}$. Together, these imply that any chart of $\mathcal{A}$ is compatible with any chart of $\mathcal{B}$, so maximality forces $\mathcal{A}=\mathcal{A}\cup\mathcal{B}=\mathcal{B}$.
